# Minimisation using the nlminb R-function

Tags: r

I would like to find the 4-dimensional vector that minimises some function f which depends on 4 variables. The first three variables take on strictly positive values; the fourth one is unconstrained. 
To do this, I would like to use R. I have tried to apply the nlminb function with lower=c(0.001, 0.001, 0.001, -Inf) as one of its optional argument. The procedure does converge but it turns out that the proposed solution does not satisfy the constraint ! 
I have an alternative solution that consists of using an exponential transformation. However, I would appreciate to figure out why R returns a solution that does not meet my requirements.

Any comment will be appreciated,
Thanks,
Marco

Comment: Can you provide the function and show you `nlminb` call so i) we can reproduce your observation, and ii) try out solutions/alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be very difficult for me to provide that function here. The reason is that it depends on a number of pre-defined stuff. 
Anyway, I am not sure to understand why this occurs but I have realized that my function sometimes returns NaN due to very very large numbers. Actually, I have some doubt about convergence. 
On the other hand, I have made some modifications and the alternative solution seems to work well. 
As a conclusion, I think that the problem came from my function, not from nlminb.

Best,
Marco